# Conditinally Testing in PlayWright 1.29.2 - click() on element works in ff but fails in chrome and webkit

Tags: javascript, testing, playwright

I am new to PlayWright and fail on my inital test setup.

We have a cookie banner on our site that sometimes appears and sometimes not. To reach the site for further testing i want to click the "Accept" button if it is present.

I have the following code that passes in Firefox but allways failes in Chrome and Webkit.

```
if (( await page.getByRole('button', {name: 'Alle akzeptieren', includeHidden:false})) ) {
              await page.getByRole('button', {name: 'Alle akzeptieren'}).click();                                                                              }
```

Message in Chrome and Webkit is always that click() interaction fails although the button seams to be present. (I can console.log the element in the test)

I have tried several versions of code but do not find a solution. Any hint would be great! Thanks.

if i run in headed mode it seems to me that only firefox shows the button. Therefor Question is why the if condition returns true for chrome and webkit. .

Comment: That if condition always returns true because a Locator object is an object and thus will always be truthy. Thus you need to use a method on it to actually see if an element exists/can be located with it, like your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution now that worked for me:

```
const count = await page.getByRole('button', {name: 'Alle    akzeptieren'}).count();
if (count === 1) {
  await page.getByRole('button', {name: 'Alle akzeptieren'}).click();
}
```